# Mybatis Logs show in junit tests but not in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, logback, mybatis, slf4j

I'm using mybatis, slf4j and logback inside a java webapp that is deployed as a war file to Tomcat.

I can see DEBUG and TRACE logs from my mybatis mappers when I run junit tests, but I can't see any logs from mybatis when I run the exact same code in Tomcat? Any ideas?

I have a single `logback.xml` in my `src/main/resources`. This ends up inside `WEB-INF/classes` inside the war when deployed to tomcat. I've configured logback as simple as possible (straight from the documentation):

```
<configuration debug="true"> 

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <!‐- encoders are  by default assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder ‐‐>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Mybatis is also configured using simple mapper config and xml files.

When I run junit tests, I see log messages from mybatis like these:

```
2021-12-17 09:41:17 DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource - Testing connection ...
2021-12-17 09:41:17 DEBUG mymapper.selectStatement - ==> Preparing: select count(*) from MY_TABLE
```

But I never see these logs when running in Tomcat.

I've read thru, and experimented with, settings as described here: https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html.

I've tried setting this in mybatis config xml:

```
 <setting name="logImpl" value="SLF4J"/>
```

I've triple checked to make sure the junit tests are running the exact same code (and using the same config files) as when I deploy to Tomcat. Mybatis logs show fine in junit stdout, but no logs from mybatis when in Tomcat?

All log messages from other libraries appear to show up fine in both junit and Tomcat environments, but for some reason mybatis doesn't show in Tomcat?

Comment: Do you specify `logImpl` setting explicitly? Please add the MyBatis configuration.

Comment: @ave, yes, I've tried setting `<setting name="logImpl" value="SLF4J"/>` but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: If you are using an older version of MyBatis, try the latest version (3.5.8 at the moment). If it still does not work, check the logger class name in your code e.g. `System.out.println(log.getClass().getName());`.